# Getting the length of nested arrays using destructuring

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with the following pattern

```
data = [
          [0,
            [
             ['a', [{}, ..., {}]],
             ['b', [{}, ..., {}]] 
            ]
          ],
          [1,
            [
             ['a', [{}, ..., {}]],
             ['b', [{}, ..., {}]] 
            ]
          ],
          .
          .
          .
      ]
```

I need to get the length of the innermost arrays of objects. Starting from an example, I'm trying this way:

```
foo = ([,[[,objects]]]) => console.log(objects.length);

data.foreach(foo);
```

According to my understanding, that should print to the console the length of each innermost array of objects. Conversely, I just get many `1`s, since `objects` seems an array containing just a single element (ie. the first one).

Can I fix it sticking to this pattern?

Bonus: is this js pattern called destructuring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is an example of [destructuring assigment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), and your example works, but you'll note that it is only logging  2 results because you are only accessing the first nested array of objects for each array passed to `foo()`.

```js
const data = [[0,[["a", [{}, {}, {}]],["b", [{}, {}, {}]]]  ],[    1, [["a", [{}, {}, {}]],["b", [{}, {}, {}]]]]];

const foo = ([,[[,objects]]]) => console.log(objects.length);

data.forEach(foo);
```

If you need to log all the nested arrays of objects you'll need to do it in two stages, the first isolating the inner arrays, and the second iterating over those inner arrays to log the lengths of each array of objects.

```js
const data = [
  [
    0,
    [
      ["a", [{}, {}, {}]],
      ["b", [{}, {}, {}]]
    ]
  ],
  [
    1,
    [
      ["a", [{}, {}, {}]],
      ["b", [{}, {}, {}]]
    ]
  ]
];

const foo = ([, inner]) =>
  inner.forEach(([, objects_arr]) => console.log(objects_arr.length));

data.forEach(foo);
```

If you break down the destructuring steps it helps to visualize it.

```
const foo = (array) => {
  console.log("array: ", array); // [0, [["a", [{}, {}, {}]],["b", [{}, {}, {}]]]]
  
  const [, inner] = array;
 
  console.log("inner: ", inner); // [["a", [{}, {}, {}]],["b", [{}, {}, {}]]]
  
  inner.forEach((arr) => {
    console.log("arr: ", arr); // ["a", [{}, {}, {}]]
    
    const [, object_arr] = arr;
    
    console.log("object_arr: ", object_arr); // [{}, {}, {}]
    console.log("object_arr.length: ", object_arr.length); // 3
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer (and for the edit) :)